# Accessing a static resource on Heroku Spring web app via browser

Tags: spring, heroku, static-resource

[image]
.

I have three `static.txt`s in my project, but a 404 error occurs when I access to https://magicsapp.herokuapp.com/static.txt.

`src/main/resources/application.properties` has this line,

```
static.resource.location=/META-INF/resources/
```

but when I commit, a warning comes:

```
Warning:(1, 1) Cannot resolve configuration property 'static.resource.location'
```

Which file (or what path) is actually accessed when I connect to that address?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The answer was `src/main/resources/static/static.txt`.